# POST Method Error 404 on local server

Tags: javascript, php

Maybe another ones view could help me. I've got a problem with using the POST method. The html file sends an request to the server. The server asks for data from the client side with the post method. This is when te error occurs. But why?? And what would be a possible solution?

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5ZtH.png)
JavaScript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
```

```js
<script>
    $("#popup").click(function() {
        var data = 'tempdata please be tehre yeeyyy';//$('.buttons').val();

        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
            'url': 'allfunctions.php',
            'type': 'POST',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'data': {post: data},
            'success': function (data) {
                if (data.finish) {
                    console.log('finished' + data);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("innerHTML", "Form Not Submited!");
                }
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    console.log("innerHTML", "Loading....");
                });
            },
            'error': function (data) {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    console.log("innerHTML", "ERROR OCCURRED!");
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP code:

```html
<?php
$post = $_POST['post'];
echo $post;
?>
```

Comment: your html so I can help you. And try to change post to post1. 'data': {post1: data}, and $post = $_POST['post1'];

Comment: looks like allfunctions.php is not in the same directory as main.html

Comment: I have changed 'type': 'POST', to 'type': 'POST1', unfortunately it did not change the problem. Also I've got both the html and php file in the same map. and (in allfunctions.php) echo "someTestThing" echo's out someTestThing. So I think this is not the cause of the error.

Comment: Thet it's not it, only in the lines that I put in the coment. And do you have the allfunctions.php in the server and in the same folder that your script, that to can be the cause of the error, like jbe pointed out.

Comment: `I have changed 'type': 'POST', to 'type': 'POST1'` - why? nobody suggested you change the request type (or method) to an invalid one! 99% chance the issue is that there is no file called `allfunctions.php` in the same folder as the html file this script tag is in - because 404 means, basically, file not found (it doesn't exactly, but for the purposes of this problem lets say it does)